# ReactiveMongo common function

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I have several functions like these:

```
  import reactivemongo.play.json.collection.JSONCollection

  def quotesFuture: Future[JSONCollection] = database.map(_.collection[JSONCollection]("quotes"))

 1:  def getByAuthor(author: String) = Action.async {
 2:    quotesFuture.flatMap{ quotes =>
 3:      quotes
 4:        .find(obj("author" -> author))
 5:        .cursor[JsObject](ReadPreference.primary)
 6:        .collect[List](maxQuotes)
 7:        .map(q => Ok(Json.toJson(q)))
 8:    }
 9:  }
10:
11:  def search(term: String) = Action.async {
12:    quotesFuture.flatMap{ quotes =>
13:      quotes
14:        .find(obj("$text" -> obj("$search" -> term)), textScore)
15:        .sort(textScore)
16:        .cursor[JsObject](ReadPreference.primary)
17:        .collect[List](maxQuotes)
18:        .map(q => Ok(Json.toJson(q)))
19:    }
20:  }
```

but there is a lot of repetition; the only thing that changes is find and sort, so I'd like to refactor as follows:

```
100:  def getByAuthor(author: String) = getList { quotes =>
101:    quotes
102:      .find(obj("author" -> author))
103:  }
104:
105:  def search(term: String) = getList { quotes =>
106:    quotes
107:      .find(obj("$text" -> obj("$search" -> term)), textScore)
108:      .sort(textScore)
109:  }
110:
111:  def getList(query: (JSONCollection) => ???) = Action.async {
112:    quotesFuture.flatMap{ quotes =>
113:      query(quotes)
114:        .cursor[JsObject](ReadPreference.primary)
115:        .collect[List](maxQuotes)
116:        .map(q => Ok(Json.toJson(q)))
117:    }
118:  }
```

**The question is what should the `???` in line 111 be?**

When asking IntelliJ to extract a method from the lines 14-15, it creates the following

```
  def tempdef(term: String, quotes: JSONCollection): GenericQueryBuilder[quotes.pack.type]#Self = {
    quotes
      .find(obj("$text" -> obj("$search" -> term)), textScore)
      .sort(textScore)
  }
```

The result type proposed by IntelliJ is pretty scary. So, `???` in line 111 should be `GenericQueryBuilder[quotes.pack.type]#Self`, but it depends on the variable `quotes`. What should I replace `???` with to make this work?

Using IntelliJ, I see that `quotes.pack` refers to:

```
case class JSONCollection(...) {...
  val pack = JSONSerializationPack
}
```

I tried replacing `???` in line 111 by `JSONSerializationPack.type`, and it compiles and works.

However, looking the implementation details of `JSONCollection` is cheating, and this could stop working if the implementation of JSONCollection changes.

So, what should the `???` in line 111 be?

Otherwise, do you see a simpler way to remove code duplication in this example?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest your `getByAuthor` and `search` return a `Cursor[JsObject]`, which allows them to have a different `ReadPreference`, and to work with non-dependent types (contrary to the query builder with depends on the underlying serialization pack of the collection, what's not understood by the IDE).

import reactivemongo.api.Cursor

```
def getByAuthor(author: String): Cursor[JsObject] = ???

def search(term: String): Cursor[JsObject] = ???

def getList(cursor: JSONCollection => Cursor[JsObject] = Action.async {
  quotesFuture.flatMap { quotes =>
    val c: Cursor[JsObject] = cursor(quotes)
    ???
  }
```

Comment: so, `def list = getList { _.find(selector = obj()).cursor[JsObject](ReadPreference.primary) }`. i still need to duplicate each time `cursor[JsObject](ReadPreference.primary)` but it is already an improvement, thanks.

Comment: i don't understand the "take care" sentence. the example compile and works. can you please rephrase it?